# ¿Cómo puedo especificar el separador que tiene un fichero csv en python?

Tags: python

Me dijeron que eso se especifica a la hora de abrir el fichero pero no se como ponerlo:

```
open(path, "rU")
```

Comment: eso me sirvio todo perfecto pero me pone el siguiente error: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 117: invalid continuation byte como especifico que me lea las palabras con tilde

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes que usar la librería CSV de Python:

```
import csv
with open(path, 'rb') as csvfile:
     record = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in record:
         print '-> '.join(row)
```

Una vez que abres el fichero, `csv.reader()` itera sobre cada línea, siendo row una lista de los valores de cada columna. Por ejemplo, supongamos un un CSV como:

personajes_famosos.csv

```
Ned Stark;Robb Stark;John Snow;
Tywin Lannister;Jaime Lannister;Tyrion Lannister;
```

Para leerlo podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
import csv
with open('personajes_famosos.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     record = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
     for row in record:
         print 'Padre:{}. Hijo1: {}. Hijo2: {} '.format(*(i for i in row))
```

Tendrías como salida:

```
Padre: Ned Stark. Hijo1: Robb Stark. Hijo2: John Snow
Padre: Tywin Lannister. Hijo1: Jaime Lannister. Hijo2: Tyrion Lannister
```

Puedes encontrar mucha más información sobre CSVs en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: +1 por Game of Thrones

Comment: -1 Yo estoy en el quinto libro y todavía no se si John Snow es hijo de Ned Stark..... mentira, +1, buena respuesta

Comment: eso me sirvio todo perfecto pero me pone el siguiente error:
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 117: invalid continuation byte
como especifico que me lea las palabras con tilde